# How do I import a jQuery library into Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

From a HTML template i am converting to vue js application with Laravel 
so like 
There is function which is drag and drop table

```
 src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
```

And Table is like

```
                    <table class="table exampleleft tble-dsg tables_ui t_draggable sourcetable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Lead Source</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="t_sortable">
                            <tr>
                                <td>lOREM IPSUM</td>
                                <td>Website</td>
                                <td> $ 750,000.00</td>
                                <td> <div class="btn-group justify-content-center">

                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <table>






$(document).ready(function() {
  var $tabs = $('.t_draggable')
  $("tbody.t_sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".t_sortable",
    //items: "> tr:not(:first)",
    appendTo: $tabs,
    helper:"clone",
    zIndex: 999990
  }).disableSelection();

  var $tab_items = $(".nav-tabs > li", $tabs).droppable({
    accept: ".t_sortable tr",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function( event, ui ) { return false; }
  });
});
```

Now When i try with vue js

i included file
require('../jquery.dataTables.min.js'); 
Than

```
mounted: function() {
        console.log('initilizede -adfg');
        var $tabs = $('.t_draggable')
        $("tbody.t_sortable").sortable({
            connectWith: ".t_sortable",
            //items: "> tr:not(:first)",
            appendTo: $tabs,
            helper:"clone",
            zIndex: 999990
        }).disableSelection();

        var $tab_items = $(".nav-tabs > li", $tabs).droppable({
            accept: ".t_sortable tr",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            drop: function( event, ui ) { return false; }
        });

}
```

So nothing is happend
If someone can help with that how can we used Jquery Library in Vue js with Laravel

I am very thankful to all

Comment: This question is not duplicate. i am asking how to include jQuery library not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run
`npm install jquery --save`

Open file `build/webpack.base.conf.js` and add `plugins`:

Add:

`const webpack = require('webpack')`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]
  ...
}
```

Comment: How to add custom library and call their function?

Answer (score 0):

Use **ProvidePlugin**

Add the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery) to the plugins array in both `build/webpack.dev.conf.js` and `build/webpack.prod.conf.js` so that jQuery becomes globally available to all your modules:

```
plugins: [


  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
]
```

Comment: jquery is available but that library is not initialized and not working

Comment: it seems like Jquery is complete its execution before Vusjs render.
try Vue.NextTick its makes the Dom ready.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick

Comment: Not working i tried with =>   jQuery('#progress-1').LineProgressbar({
     percentage: 25
   });
   console.log('Vue is Great');
   this.msg = 'VUE is great';
  });